# Azure App Service and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am developing .Net Core APIs using C#. In my use case, I have password protected Word documents. I need to open these documents programatically and read all the contents from it.

I cannot use OpenXML SDK, since it does not support processing of password protected documents.
I do not want to use any REST APIs since my documents contains GDPR/personal data.

I am trying to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` nuget package, which works fine locally. But does not work when we publish my APIs into Azure App Service. Since this package is a Office 365 package, this is expecting Microsoft Word to be installed, which cannot be done in Azure App Service.

Can someone suggest me if there any way where we can deploy `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` libraries into Azure App Service?

Is there any other alternative nuget packages available to which supports extracting text from password protected word document?

Regards, Madhu

Comment: Have you come up with a solution for this ?